# jQuery,get second li tag content

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I want to replace the separator symbol mentioned in the following structure,for that i need to get the position first,can anybody help to proceed

This is my structure

```
  <div>
       <ul>    
           <li><a>text</a></li>    
           <li><span> > </span></li>    
      <li></li>   
      <li></li>    
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: please fist specify what is you is main selection > or second li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").html();
```

Or, if you need just text, you can go with:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").text();
```

Comment: $("ul li:nth-child(2)").text(); this is simply superb.tanq

Comment: i used this $("ul li:nth-child(2)").text(); to get ">" value.i jus want to replace tat with "|".i tried to achieve by   var text=$('ul li:nth-child(2)').text();
text.replace(">","|");   but i cant.do u have idea
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').html(text);

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to select your second li:

```
$("div ul li:eq(1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try css3 selectors

```
$('ul li:nth-child(2)')
```

for more insormation see 
[nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

this way you can also get even or odd selections like`nth-child(2n+1)` `nth-child(2n)` and also use this selectors in you css and use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) for work in ie and old browsers

Comment: very useful tanq.i tried this same syntax before by leaving the ul

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div ul').children('li').eq(1);
```

If you want to get the content, you'll need to append `.html()`:

```
$('div ul').children('li').eq(1).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var position = $('li:contains(>)').index();
```